# How to add a second clock to a panel showing the current UTC time

Tags: xfce

I want to have a second clock in my panel not showing the localtime, instead showing the UTC time. How is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

It's very easy. You just add another clock panel: right click onto the bar -> Panel -> Add new items -> Clock. Then you right click on this newly created Clock panel -> Properties -> Timezone -> UCT. Done ;)

Comment: For me it is possible to add a new clock widget, but it is not possible to change the timezone of the clock widget.